# cross domain request with jQuery jsonp to remote ASP.NET web service

Tags: jquery, web-services, jsonp

here i am giving input in json format.but i am not getting the output.could any one please solve this problem.

i have some queries regarding jsonp :

1)I have a doubt inorder to call remote web services using jsonp,should we have to send data in json format or querystring format.

2)Here if we access the url and give input then we will get o/p in xml format. so i just want to know whether jsonp wont work for webservices which gives xml as output.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myQuerySuggestions() {
    var searchText = document.getElementById('txtsearch').value;
                searchText = "'" + searchText + "'";
                var jasonData = "{" + 'Celsius:' + searchText + "}";
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,            
        data:jasonData,
        jsonpCallback: blah,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, status) {
            alert(status+" status");
        },
        error: function () { alert("error"); }
    });

}
function blah(data) {
   alert("called");
   alert(data);
   // var result = (typeof data.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + data.d + ')') : data.d;
   // $('#summary').html('<p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>');
   // $('#summary').html(result);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
<label for="txtsearch">
    Enter country:
</label>
<input type="text" id="txtsearch" size="43" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="myQuerySuggestions();return false;" />
<div id="summary" runat="server"></div>
</div>
 </form>
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please tell me if the question is not clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever service you are calling should return JSONP for Ajax call with `dataType: "jsonp"` to work.

XML response is not JSONP response - there is no magic conversion from one to another.

Comment: ok thank u very much.is there any mistake in my code which i have mentioned above.it is not working.

Comment: @Revanthkumar, code looks ok, it just is not expected to succeed. So in a sense it behave as expected...

Comment: @Revanthkumar, one more try - there is no errors in the code, just service you are calling will not return you JSONP response and thus code always appropriately go through failure code path. I guess I'm not getting what is your expectation - XML is not JSONP, so code should fail.

Answer (score 0):

edited the program Code..this code works fine.but the service which i am calling will not return JSONP for Ajax call.so the output of this code will be undefined.